# Is it safe to use the address 0.0.0.0 on a Postgres database?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm following a guide on how to setup a Postgres database with remote access (using pgAdmin 4). If I want to use the remote access with success then I have to change the configs and one of them is to add the entries 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all ::/0 md5
```

I googled a bit about that and now I'm not sure if that is safe. Does 0.0.0.0/0 allow any IP? Or is it only for the local network?

Comment: It is all `IPv4` addresses. See [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) `address` section for more information. So you would be opening the database to the world, dependent on what your firewall rules are. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: It depends on which setting you're adding those addresses to. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

`0.0.0.0/0` means any IPv4 address. This means it match all the IPv4 interfaces that exist in your box.

If your machine is not in the outskirts of your datacenter, it's probably safe. And if you have firewall rules on top of that, it's likely moot anyway. But if it's either on hardware, local firewall or in your pg config, this must be handled by some layer.

Answer (score 1):

It is open to world, at least to whatever extent of it your network itself is open to.  One for the local network would look something like '192.168.0.0/16' or '10.0.0.0/8' in ipv4, and I-don't-know-what in ipv6.

But that doesn't necessarily mean it is unsafe.  If your local network has a firewall at its edge, then that will prevent any random computer in the world from connecting to you.  And even if they can contact the server, they would still need to guess the password online (given the rest of your pg_hba line) or exploit an unpatched security bug in PostgreSQL.  If your password is not crap and your users who know them don't leak them, this would be close to impossible.